# Why did Apache IoTDB suddenly shutdown when writing data through interface?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Has anyone encountered this kind of problem? When writing data into Apache IoTDB using the data interface, IoTDB suddenly shutdown and cannot normally continue the writing data process after restarting. How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the log of Apache IoTDB. Normally this problem may be caused by `wal` storage is full. If there is excessive data causing `wal` in IoTDB to be full, it is recommended to close all `merge` progress. This setting can be changed in the DataNode configuration.